# scheduledtask to update svn directory creates multiple processes

Tags: windows-server-2008, svn, scheduled-task, batch, tortoisesvn

We have a fairly standard web setup, with a windows 2008 server hosting our website and the directories being under control of SVN, with tortoise SVN as the preferred provider.

One of the SVN folders is our content delivery network, we need to update this folder quite a fair amount so it has all the latest pictures and content.  So we created a batch file and attached it to scheduled task so it would update the folder every 15 minutes or so.  We used this code to run the process:

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\websites\_qpr\_files" /closeonend:1
TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\websites\_qpr\_images" /closeonend:1
TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\websites\_qpr\_stuff" /closeonend:1
```

When we left this running for a day or so, we found that the server had filled up with hundreds of Tortoisesvn processes and we had to reboot the server to gain control (we might not have needed to but we did).  This doesn't seem correct, with this script surely it should only create 3 processes and kill them after a successful update?

many thanks for any help you can give with this.